# What microtasks are enqueued with a Promise that resolves with a Promise in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise, v8

I am trying to understand what microtask get enqueued when a Promise is resolved with another Promise.

For example, what microtasks are enqueued with the following code?

```
const p1 = Promise.resolve("A");
const p2 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(p1));
p2.then(() => console.log("THEN"));
```

I have found no way to inspect the MicrotaskQueue in V8.
After "reading" the [ECMA specification of "Promise Resolve Functions"](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise-resolve-functions), this is what I understood:

The call `resolve(p2)` in the executor of Promise `p2` enqueues a microtask that chains `p1` to `p2`. Lets call it the **chaining microtask**.

After the block of code is executed, the stack is empty and V8 processes the microtask queue. The queue contains only the chaining microtask.

The chaining microtask calls the `then` method of `p1` passing as callback functions the `resolve` and `reject` functions of `p2`.
`p1` is a resolved promise therefore the call to `then` enqueues a new microtask to execute the then callbacks. Lets call it **p1-then-p2 microtask**.

The microtask queue now contains only the p1-then-p2 task.

V8 executes the p1-then-p2 task. The task enqueues a new microtask to execute the last `then` in the code: `p2.then(() => console.log("THEN"))`. Lets call it **p2-then-console**.

The microtask queue now contains only the p2-then-console task.
V8 executes the task printing "THEN" in console.

The microtask queue is empty, the program exits.

Do I understood correctly?

Comment: Perhaps you're just trying to go for an academic understanding here, but trying to follow promise queueing when there are NO actual asynchronous operations involved (which is NEVER what the real world looks like) is generally pretty pointless.  In the real world, promises get resolved when an asynchronous operation completes and that dominates the timing and all the details you have here are completely irrelevant.

Comment: Using the terminology in the ES specification, as a promise is resolved or rejected, it calls [HostEnqueuePromiseJob()](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/executable-code-and-execution-contexts.html#sec-hostenqueuepromisejob) which adds a microtask to the promise queue.  That microtask (when it gets a chance to run) will then call the `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers for that promise accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I understood correctly?

Yes.

However, don't write code that will depend on the order of microtasks. This is specified in detail for deterministic results across js implementations, not for user code to rely on. It might even change with ECMAScript versions.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. No, I am not going to write code that depends on the order, I just need to understand the mechanism to understand what was happening in another issue I had.